# How can i implement GTMOAuth in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, oauth

i need to implement GTMOAuth to my iOS app..for this i have downloaded the OAuth Library and write some code

```
- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)myCustomAuth {


NSString *myConsumerKey = @"f964039f2d7bc82054";    // pre-registered with service
NSString *myConsumerSecret = @"c9a749c0f1e30c9246a3be7b2586434f"; // pre-assigned by service

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
auth = [[[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                    consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                     privateKey:myConsumerSecret] autorelease];

// setting the service name lets us inspect the auth object later to know
// what service it is for
auth.serviceProvider = @"Custom Auth Service";

return auth;
}



- (void)signInToCustomService {

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alpha.easyreceipts.com/api/v1/oauth/request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alpha.easyreceipts.com/api/v1/oauth/access_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alpha.easyreceipts.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize"];
NSString *scope = @"http://alpha.easyreceipts.com/api/v1/";

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];

// set the callback URL to which the site should redirect, and for which
// the OAuth controller should look to determine when sign-in has
// finished or been canceled
//
// This URL does not need to be for an actual web page
[auth setCallback:@"http://alpha.easyreceipts.com/api/v1/"];

// Display the autentication view
GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                            language:nil
                                                     requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                   authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                      accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                      authentication:auth
                                                      appServiceName:@"My App: Custom Service"
                                                            delegate:self
                                                           finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];
viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                       animated:YES];
}
```

but further i don't know how to implement it.Please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to implement an OAuth authentication system with the GTM library, you should get this one.
You can find the complete sources of GTMOAuth [here](https://github.com/jdg/gtm-oauth).

Secondly, you can find an example of how to use it in the git repository too. You should find everything you need to at least authenticate.
If you have any more problem, please provide more informations.